# Regex.Split create new line

Tags: c#, regex, winforms, newline

Basically trying to create a new line in the list box when data is imported or added. For example an address would need a new line

```
2
example road
example
```

At this moment it is showing the item in one line rather than 3 lines.

```
private void txtPhrase_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (string s in Regex.Split("", "\r\n"))
        txtPhrase.Items.Add(s);
}
```

Unsure on what to put as the string input? As there are different inputs.

Comment: Where is your Data coming from?

Comment: User entered data and a SQL database

Comment: so your input is one string that you want to split into multiple ones? Could you provide example data?

Comment: Pretty much yes, so an address would be example data? If somebody enters data such as:
AddressLine1
AddressLine2
AddressLine3
Postcode

Comment: @JamieHennerley How do you know where AddressLine1 ends and AddressLine2 starts? What is the rule?

Comment: Well you have to make the user enter the adress in a well defined format so that you can parse it.

Comment: I think it would be better (and easier) to provide multiple inputs for Street, state and so on.

Comment: The user can input any data, I was just using an address as the example because it's common data..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The listbox does not support functionality to split a single list item on to multiple lines. You may want to consider using seperate items or a different control on your form.

Answer (score 0):

Input is the name of the string Regex is receiving. It would be something like:

```
string[] values = new string[] { "2", "example road", "example" };

foreach (string stringvalue in values)
{
 string[] ResultRegex= Regex.Split(stringvalue, "pattern");
}
```

By the way, I dont think you need regex, you need to use String.Split().
For example:

```
string[] splitedValues = values.Split('\r\n');
```

Comment: The input is going to be different every time though seeing as the user enters different values? Would that not make a difference?

Comment: I dont think you need regex. You need String.Split()

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea dont know if it is working, but i use - Environment.NewLine -

```
String.Format(" after this text a new line {0}",Environment.NewLine)
```